# Android Studio 2.3.1 Missing Debugger Pane

Tags: android

I have gone through a few articles here on StackOverflow about the missing debugger feature in Android Studio 2.3.1 and have yet to find a fix.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Logs to the rescue!

[image]

Enable both plugins: Android NDK support and NDK workspace Support.

Android Studio will ask you to do a few installs, including LLDB.

Tada!
[image]